# How do I create an Rx sequence by running tasks over original sequence's values?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I have a sequence of type `IObservable<T>` and a function that maps `T, CancellationToken` to a `Task<U>`.  What's the cleanest way of getting an `IObservable<U>` out of them?

I need the following semantics:

- each tasks starts after the previous item's task has finished
- if a task has been cancelled or faulted, it is skipped
- the order of the original sequence is strictly preserved

Here's the signature as I see it:

```
public static IObservable<U> Select<T, U> (
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, CancellationToken, Task<U>> selector
);
```

I haven't written any code yet but I will unless someone beats me to it.
In any case, I'm not familiar with operators like `Window`, so my solution will likely be less elegant.

I need the solution in C# 4, but C# 5 answers are also welcome for the sake of comparison.

---

If you're curious, below is my real-world scenario, more or less:

```
Dropbox.GetImagesRecursively ()
    .ObserveOn (SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Select (DownloadImage)
    .Subscribe (AddImageToFilePicker);
```

Comment: Wow, I just realized `SelectMany` has **exactly** the same signature. Alas, it doesn't wait for tasks to finish.

Comment: I think that in general, it's a bad idea to ignore exceptions. They should be at least logged, or something like that.

Comment: @svick: You're right, I'll revise this design after the first implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me so far:

```
public static IObservable<U> Select<T, U> (
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, CancellationToken, Task<U>> selector)
{
    return source
        .Select (item => 
            Observable.Defer (() => 
                Observable.StartAsync (ct => selector (item, ct))
                    .Catch (Observable.Empty<U> ())
            ))
        .Concat ();
}
```

We map a deferred task-based exception-swallowing observable to each item, and then concat them.

---

My thought process went like this.

I noticed that one of the `SelectMany` overloads does *almost* exactly what I wanted and even has exactly the same signature. It didn't satisfy my needs though:

- it creates tasks as original items come up, whereas I needed to wait for each task to finish
- it offers no option to skip canceled and faulted tasks

I looked at this overload's implementation and noticed it uses `FromAsync` to handle task creation and cancellation:

```
public virtual IObservable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TTaskResult, TResult> (IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, CancellationToken, Task<TTaskResult>> taskSelector, Func<TSource, TTaskResult, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return SelectMany_<TSource, TTaskResult, TResult> (
        source,
        x => FromAsync (ct => taskSelector (x, ct)),
        resultSelector
    );
}
```

I turned my eye to `FromAsync` to see how it was implemented, and was pleasantly surprised to find it was composable as well:

```
public virtual IObservable<TResult> FromAsync<TResult> (Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> functionAsync)
{
    return Defer (() => StartAsync (functionAsync));
}
```

I reused `Defer` and `StartAsync`, while also adding `Catch` to swallow errors. The combination of `Defer` and `Concat` ensures tasks wait for each other and start in the original order.